# How to track Firefox's Internet Usage for each tab?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, plugins, network-monitoring

My firefox is hogging up way too much of my bandwidth but I can't seem to figure out what is consuming all that data. I have only 2-3 active tabs, the rest 50 tabs from previous reboot are on sleep.

I do have vnstat and conky installed but those were not very helpful in tracking which tab was consuming all that data.
for eg,
[ThisImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBeNN.jpg)
In the above image you can see that googleusercontent and amazonaws are getting used by two of the processes but the 3 tabs that I had open were nytimes, bing and askubuntu.
so it's quite confusing.

Firefox's Network Monitor tool is also useless as it doesn't track all the tabs but only tracks tabs for which you open it. :( Is there a way I can make it track all the tabs using a shell script or something?

I tried finding some add-on or tool that could track per tab bandwidth usage but without any luck so I was wondering if there is any way I could do that?

also, I am wondering if there is a way to put all the tabs not used in the past 30 minutes to sleep?

Thank You Very Much for any help.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried finding some add-on or tool that could track per tab bandwidth
> usage but without any luck so I was wondering if there is any way I
> could do that?

Yes, this can be done by entering `about:performance` in your browser address bar. It will present you with a list of your open tabs/add-ons with the Energy Impact and memory usage...

[image]

> I am wondering if there is a way to put all the tabs not used in the past 30 minutes to sleep?

This can be done too.

install Sleep Mode from the Mozilla Addons site.

```
Search for Sleep Mode, by matico, and click the Add to Firefox button. 
When prompted, click Add and then click OK.
```

Once installed, click the Sleep Mode icon and select if you want to ignore pinned tabs (and various Google offerings), and click START. All but your working tab will go to sleep (as indicated by the moon icon in the tab).

To disable Sleep Mode, click the same icon and click DISABLE.

That's all there is to hibernating tabs in Firefox with the Sleep Mode extension.

As for internet use monitoring there are a few more things to consider:

You could try entering `about:networking` in your browser address bar and selecting the monitor which you wish to use from the list on the left of the screen:

[image]

and consider online tools listed in [this](https://www.tek-tools.com/network/what-is-bandwidth-monitoring) resource.

[reference](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-hibernate-inactive-tabs-in-firefox-with-sleep-mode/)

Comment: If this addresses your question please consider [accepting it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps upvoting as well since this will help others in the future with a similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: "about:performance" doesn't show Internet Data usage. it only shows memory usage.
I already know about it but as it didn't track internet data so I didn't think it was relevant to my question.

I have used that "sleep Mode" add-on, I don't think it is being kept up-to-date with the new firefox versions. as it reloads all the tabs over and over, and hangs firefox and makes it unusable. all this, with my i5 processor and 16 gb of ram.
I tried restarting the computer and everything but it was of no use. Sleep mode addon project looks dead to me.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and I would really appreciate any other recommendations and any help whatsover you can provide. :) Thank You very much. :) :)

Comment: also, if you like the question, please consider upvoting it as it will be helpful to others too.
I have searched the whole internet, there is no information available regarding this anywhere so would be a good question. :)

Comment: @Nick I've added some more references to my answer.

Comment: This sockets tab is a good suggestion, I didn't know this before but it seems it is only showing packets sent and received and not the actual bandwidth consumed by those ip addresses.
also, the bandwidth consumption is not divided based on a per tab basis so one tab could reference more than 1 ip address and will be listed as a more than one on sockets.
what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: and Regarding Sleep Mode addon, It seems the addon was last updated on Nov-2019 so doesn't seem outdated. I think the issue that it is causing on my firefox is because of my treestyletab addon. sleep mode is conflicting with it and is is reloading all tabs over and over and crashing firefox. GOT ANY OTHER SUGGESTIONS PLEASE? :)
THANK YOU SOOO SOO MUCH FOR TRYING TO HELP, REALLY APPRECIATE IT. :)

Comment: please feel free to correct me if I am wrong in any part of my reply. :) requesting you to please reply if you could. Thank You very much.